# Laravel - How to specify the User Role to be displayed

Tags: laravel, api

I am working on a Web Application using Laravel-5.8 as the backend. I am combining two classes: User and Role

ApiController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if(!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Add Users'))
        return response()->json([ "message" => 'User do not have permission'], 401);

    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:6'
    ]);

    $user = new User([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        'activation_token' => str_random(60),
        'address' => $request->email,
        'about' => $request->email,
    ]);

    if($request->role)
        foreach($request->role as $role)
            $user->assignRole($role);
    else {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Role Not Found!'
        ], 401);
    }

    $user->school_id = Auth::user()->school_id;

    if($request->address)
        $user->address = $request->address;

    if($request->about)
        $user->about = $request->about;

    $user->save();

    $avatar = Avatar::create(strtoupper($user->name))->getImageObject()->encode('png');
    Storage::put('avatars/'.$user->id.'/avatar.png', (string) $avatar);
    $user->notify(new SignupActivate($user));

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully Added New User!'
    ], 201);
}
```

From the code above, I don't want to display all the Roles. I want to use the foreach statement to only select and display these two Roles: Admin, Staff.
That is, where role_name = Admin, Staff.

```
foreach($request->role as $role)
    $user->assignRole($role);
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to display them or assign the roles, please clarify on this option so that I can help may be

Comment: @Matovu Ronald - I want to assign roles, but only two roles should be displayed: Admin and Staff. I don't want to be able to assign all the roles

Comment: I am gonna be posting an answer on the way you should go about it very soon give a few seconds.

Comment: I have posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can go about that in this way.

1. You can use the Laravel filter method which is in the documentation here [Laravel Collection filter Method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter)
2. This method returns an array of items that have passed a given condition
3. You convert your roles request into a collection first
4. Then use a condition like

   **return if($role == 'Admin' || $role == 'Staff')**
   Where you see **return $value > 2;**

---

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4]);

$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value > 2;
});
```

$filtered->all();

// [3, 4]